# Structure theorem for a class of idempotent monoids (where $xy = x$ or $xy = y$ for all $x, y$)

Tags: reference-request, semigroups-and-monoids

**Question.** Is there any structure theorem for the class of monoids $H$ with the property that $xy = x$ or $xy = y$ for all $x, y \in H$? Or does this look hopeless for some good reasons?

A monoid with the above property is idempotent and need not be commutative. Examples include (i) the unitization of a left (resp., right) singular semigroup, where one starts with a set $X$ and defines an associative binary operation on $X$ by taking $xy := x$ (resp., $xy := y$) for all $x, y \in X$; or a chain of subsets of a "universe" $V$ made into a monoid by the operation that maps two sets in the chain to their union.

I'm aware of the work of D. McLean in [*Idempotent semigroups*, Amer. Math. Monthly **61** (1954), 110-113] and N. Kimura (e.g., [*The structure of idempotent semigroups. I*, Pacific J. Math. **8** (1958), No. 2, 257-275]) on the structure of idempotent semigroups, but I'm wondering if something more precise/specific can be done/has been done for the monoids of this thread.

**Motivation.** The question arises from the study of the arithmetic of a certain monoid of sets, $P_{\text{fin},1}(H)$, naturally attached to an arbitrary monoid $H$ (hereby written multiplicatively). More precisely, $P_{\text{fin},1}(H)$ is obtained by endowing the family of all finite subsets of $H$ containing the identity $1_H$ with the operation of setwise multiplication induced by $H$ (in some circles, this thing is commonly referred to as the *reduced (finitary) power monoid* of $H$); and one can show that, if $H$ is commutative and satisfies the above property (that $xy = x$ or $xy = y$ for all $x, y \in H$), then $P_{\text{fin},1}(H)$ enjoys a form of unique factorization (into irreducibles).

Comment: For a semigroup this is the same as a semigroup in which every subset is a subsemigroup. [In particular in a monoid, the complement of $\{1\}$ will be a subsemigroup, so restricting to monoids looks a bit artificial.] So one might get a lot of information by classifying small finite such semigroups.

Comment: More precisely, call this "strongly idempotent semigroup". For a semigroup $S$ write $mS$ for the unitization $S\sqcup\{1\}$. Then every finite semigroup as you consider can be written canonically as $m^nS$ for some strongly idempotent semigroup $S$ that is not a monoid (namely, remove units step by step). This decomposition is canonical. Thus (in the finite case) one is reduced to classify those strongly idempotent semigroups without unit. For instance, $m^n\emptyset$ is an $n$-element chain with union as law.

Comment: A little further: any finite strongly idempotent semigroup $S$ has a unique partition $S=S_1\sqcup S_2\sqcup\dots\sqcup S_n$, such that $S_i\neq\emptyset$ and $S_iS_j\subset S_i$ for all $i\le j$, and $S_i$ is simple ($\neq\emptyset$, no 2-sided ideal other that $S_i$ and $\emptyset$). The law on each $S_i$ determines the whole law (clear). So the classification reduces to the simple case. The smallest simple strongly idempotent semigroups are 2-elements sets with law $xy=x$, and its opposite; if I'm correct there's no other on $\le 3$ elements.

Comment: My first impression is all you can do is build a chain of J-classes where each J-class acts as the identity on those below it and each J-class is a left or right zero semigroup

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg I was just finishing typing up a long-winded answer which I think amounts to what you just said

Comment: @YemonChoi,  your answer is great.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Seeing as no one in BanAlg world took an interest in https://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~choiy1/pubmath/papers/HHbands.html I feel compelled to try and get maximum mileage out of the hours I spent reading Howie's book :)

Comment: @YemonChoi, i saw that paper

Comment: For problems like this, it may be a good idea to count the number of such algebras and then put the sequence into the online encyclopedia of integer sequences. I did a brute force search (backtracking is more efficient but harder to code), and I got 1,4,20,138 which is https://oeis.org/A292932. These algebras are known as quasi-trivial semigroups. And I found a paper on this https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.09162.pdf.

Comment: I had not heard this name before.  But then again this is such a rigid notion I wouldn't be surprised if it has been rediscovered again and again. But I.think Yemon's answer says pretty much what the paper says in a more efficient way modulo counting

Comment: These seemed to be first studied by Redei in Rédei, L. Algebra I; Pergamon Press: Oxford, UK, 1967.  See Theorem 50 of section 27 where it gives Yemon's result.  I've seen them called breakable semigroups and Redei semigroups in old papers. See https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02276097 for example

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Why not move your comments on Rédei's work to an answer?

Comment: I'd be curious whether the variety generated by breakable semigroups is finitely based. It is locally finite (easy exercise, given the structural result). Identities in $\le 3$ variables are generated by $x^2=x$, $xyxzx=xyzx$, $xzyxy=xzxy$, $xyxzy=xyzy$. Two semigroup words in a free breakable semigroup over a set $K$ represent the same element iff they have the same letters (not counting multiplicities) and for every subset $J$ of $K$, whenever removing all letters of $J$ from these words, the resulting words have the same first and last letter.

Comment: (My initial comments are quite obsolete now, but anyway in the terminology I suggested, the classification result says that the simple breakable semigroups are precisely the nonempty sets endowed with either the law $xy=x$, or the law $xy=y$ — which are nonisomorphic unless the set is a singleton.)

Comment: @YCor, every variety of bands of finitely based.  There is a complete description of the lattice of band varieties

Comment: @SalvoTringali, is it necessary? Two people have already given the complete structural description so it's more a historical remark

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Maybe not necessary, but you provided the reference that nails the problem and the original question includes the "reference request" tag.

Comment: @YCor, it should be the variety of regular bands.  This is the variety generated by a left zero semigroup with adjoined identity and a right zero semigroup with adjoined zero and it is defined by $zxyz=zxzyz$.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_(algebra)#Varieties_of_bands

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg great! (It should be generated by $zxyz=zxzyz$ among bands, hence, by this and the idempotent identity $z^2=z$ among semigroups, since the latter doesn't follow from the former.) I didn't realize that $xzxyz=xzyz$ follows from these identities but this is indeed very easy.

Comment: @YCor, sorry I was just defining it among bands.  There are lots of tricks to show identities among bands imply other ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The semigroups in the question seem to have first been introduced by Redei in his book Algebra. Vol 1. The book was originally published in Hungarian in 1954, and then German in 1959.  The English edition is 1967. In the English version they are called breakable semigroups. The main result in the English edition about them is Theorem 50 of section 27 which is the result in the previous answers that you have a bunch of left/right zero semigroups indexed by a totally ordered set with the product of elements from different indices the one in the smaller indexed set. This is more or less immediate from the definition and the fact that a band is a semilattice of rectangular bands if you are familiar with semigroup structure theory. This is more or less what @YemonChoi explains in his answer in detail.

Answer (score 5):

**The non-associative case**

We say that an operation $\cdot$ on a set $X$ is conservative if for all $x,y\in X$ either $xy=x$ or $xy=y$. If $\cdot$ is conservative, then we can define two relations $R,S$ by setting $R=\{(x,y)\mid xy=x\}$ and $S=\{(x,y)\mid xy=y\}$. Then $R\cup S=X^2$ and $R\cap S=1_X$. Therefore, $R,S$ are complements in the Boolean lattice $[1_X,X^2]$. In fact, the conservative operations on $X$ are in a one-to-one correspondence with the elements in the interval $[1_X,X^2]$. If the operation $\cdot$ is associative, then the operations $R,S$ are pre-orderings; $(x,y)\in R$ precisely when there is some $r$ with $ry=x$, and $(x,y)\in S$ precisely when there is an $s$ with $xs=y$.

**The associative case**

If $X$ is a small set, then it is not too difficult to write a brute force search algorithm that counts the number of conservative semigroups on a set $X$ in order to count the number of conservative semigroups (for the programmers out there, backtracking algorithms are faster but harder to code). The number of conservative semigroups on a set $X$ with $|X|=n$ is sequence [A292932](https://oeis.org/A292932) on the online encyclopedia of integer sequences.

The conservative semigroups have been investigated in the ~2019 paper [Quasitrivial semigroups: characterizations and enumerations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.09162v3) by Miguel Couceiro, Jimmy Devillet, Jean-Luc Marichal. In that paper, conservative binary operations are called quasitrivial; conservative binary operations were studied several decades before that paper was written. In that paper, we have the following characterization of the conservative semigroups.

If $\preceq$ is a pre-ordering, then define an equivalence relation $\simeq_\preceq$ by letting $x\simeq_\preceq y$ precisely when $x\preceq y\preceq x$. We say that a pre-ordering $\preceq$ is a pre-linear ordering if whenever $x,y\in X$, either $x\preceq y$ or $y\preceq x$.

Theorem: An operation $F:X^2\rightarrow X$ is associative and conservative if and only if there is a pre-linear ordering $\preceq$ on $X$ where if $A,B$ are equivalence classes with respect to $\simeq_\preceq$, then

1. $F|_{A\times B}=\max_{\preceq}|_{A\times B}$ whenever $A\neq B$, and
2. $F|_{A\times B}=(\pi_1)|_{A\times B}$ or $F|_{A\times B}=(\pi_2)|_{A\times B}$ whenever $A\neq B.$

**An opinion about terminology**

What I call a conservative binary operation has been called a strongly idempotent, breakable, or quasi-trivial binary operation by others. The term 'conservative' is consistent with the use of this term in cellular automata and reversible circuits. For example, a logic gate $C:F_2^n\rightarrow F_2^n$ is said to be conservative if $\mathbf{x}$ and $C(\mathbf{x})$ always have the same number of $1$-bits.

We can generalize these two notions of conservativism with this definition; a function $f:X^n\rightarrow X^m$ where $n\geq m$ is said to be conservative if whenever $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=(y_1,\dots,y_m)$, we have
$|\{j\mid 1\leq j\leq m,y_j=a\}|\leq|\{i\mid 1\leq i\leq n,x_i=a\}|$ for each $a\in X$.

Comment: As I pointed out in the comments above these semigroups were first studied and classified by Redei in 1959 (the English translation of his book is 1967). The English translation called them breakable semigroups

Comment: @JosephVanName. Thanks for the ref. In the associative case, it seems to me that the theorem cited in your post follows at once from Theorem 50 in the 1967 edition of Rédei's _Algebra I_ (which I learned about from Benjamin Steinberg's comments). Also, I don't see a reason for calling a total preorder a quasi-ordering (in fact, it sounds unnecessarily confusing).

Comment: I agree that the terms 'total preorder' or 'linear preorder' or 'pre-linear order' or 'pre-total order' are more descriptive and better than 'weak ordering' or 'quasi-ordering'. The term 'conservative' is more descriptive and better than 'breakable', 'quasi-trivial', 'strongly idempotent'. The terms 'strongly', 'quasi', and 'trivial' are overused in mathematics. The term 'conservative' is somewhat consistent with its use in cellular automata and reversible computing.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some initial thoughts (but I am both rusty and away from my reference books). I am going to use the terminology "band" rather than "idempotent semigroup" and "semilattice" rather than "commutative idempotent semigroup" since this is the terminology in Howie's book(s) which is where I first learned this topic.

---

If I recall correctly: the structure theory for bands that you mention implies in particular that every band $B$ admits a surjective homomorphism q onto a canonical "structure semilattice" $L$, in which each fibre $R_t:=q^{-1}(t)$ is a so-called rectangular band.

Since the defining property you are interested in passes to quotients, if $S$ is a semigroup of the form you describe, we know that its "structure semilattice" $L$ must be totally ordered.

A *rectangular band* is a semigroup $R$ which satisfies the equation $xyz=xz$ for all $x,y,z\in R$. Every rectangular band is isomorphic to one of the following form: take non-empty sets $I$ and $J$ and equip $I\times J$ with the multiplication defined by $(i_1,j_1)\cdot (i_2,j_2) = (i_1,j_2)$. If we also require that this semigroup satisfies the "defining condition" in your question, then:

- if $|I|\geq 2$ then $|J|=1$;
- if $|J|\geq 2$ then $|I|=1$.

In the former case, we have $xy=x$ for all $x,y\in R$; in the second case, we have $xy=y$ for all $x,y\in R$.

Thus, if $S$ is a semigroup of the form you describe, and $L$ is its structure semilattice, with quotient map $q:S\to L$ then $L$ is totally ordered and for each $t\in L$ the fibre $R_t=q^{-1}(\{t\})$ is either left absorbing or right absorbing in the sense of the previous paragraph.

Now let $s,t\in L$ with $s\neq t$; without loss of generality $s\preceq t$, that is to say $st=s=ts$. We know that for each $x\in R_s$ and $y\in R_t$ we have $xy,yx\in R_s$; since $xy\in\{x,y\}$ we must have $xy=yx=x$. So whenever we multiply two elements in different fibres, their product is always "the element in the lower fibre".

I think this determines the global multiplication table of $S$, provided one is given the fibring map $q:S\to L$. I suspect that conversely, given a totally ordered semilattice $L$ and a family $(R_t)_{t\in L}$ where each $R_t$ is either a left-absorbing or a right-absorbing semigroup, then $S=\bigsqcup_{t\in L} R_t$ will become a semigroup satisfying $xy\in\{x,y\}$ for all $x,y\in S$ provided we adopt the "when multiplying elements in different fibres, take the one in the lowest fibre" rule -- I admit I haven't thought in detail about verifying associativity.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Indeed as I was typing this I thought "I had better hurry up before Ben turns up and gives a 1-line answer"

Comment: Sorry I had moved my comment to the above.  Associate it is no worry.  You can always take two semigroups S,T and make their union a semigroup by having elements of S fix T. You are just doing this iteratively adding left or right zeroe semigroups fixing the previous ones

Comment: Is a totally ordered semilattice the same thing as a totally ordered set? If so, the associativity of multiplication can be witnessed by the following rule for multiplying $n$ elements: Of all elements in the lowest fiber, take the left one if it's a left-absorbing fiber or the right one if it's a right-absorbing fiber.

Comment: Thanks Ben. @WillSawin Yes, in any poset which admits greatest lower bounds, defining $x\cdot y = {\rm glb}(x,y)$ yields a commutative idempotent semigroup; conversely, given a commutative idempotent semigroup, one obtains a partial order by defining $x\preceq y \iff xy=x$.

Comment: @YemonChoi My comment had nothing to do with the commutative case, and in fact was just explaining the same thing Ben did. I didn't realize his comment had the solution.

Comment: @WillSawin Sure, I was just trying to sketch why the two possible interpretations of "totally ordered semlattice" give exactly the same thing

Comment: For the record, the factorization of a rectangular band mentioned in this answer is Lemma 1 in the PJM paper by N. Kimura cited in the OP.

Comment: @SalvoTringali, this factorization of a rectangular band is certainly much older.  It's an immediate consequence of Rees's theorem from 1940 on completely simple semigroups.  Rectangular bands are the completely simple semigroups with trivial maximal subgroup.  Rectangular bands can be defined by the simpler identity $xyx=x$.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Yeah, I didn't want to imply anything about the origins of the decomposition. My intention was rather to provide a reference. In any case, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I have no idea if in 1940 the term rectangular band existed but the decomposition is the band special case of Rees's theorem, actually at least in the finite case it follows from Sushkevich's theorem from around 1926.